# Performance of returning a new array and modifying a passed-in array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

[[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529786/altering-numpy-function-output-array-in-place)]

In the snapshot below, I compare the speed of

- modifying an existing array via slice assignment
- just returning a new, modified array

It seems that the latter is faster.  Why should this be the case?

---

EDIT: Updated with suggestions, and a version that uses numpy's vectorized `add()`, which is now the fastest.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `x + 1` will create a new array.
- `y[:] = x + 1`: create a new array and copy all the data to `y`
- `y = x + 1`: create a new array and bind name `y` to this new array.
- `np.add(x, 1, out=y)`: don't create a new array, it's the fastest.

Here is the code:

```
x = np.zeros(1000000)
y = np.zeros_like(x)
%timeit x + 1
%timeit y[:] = x + 1
%timeit np.add(x, 1, out=y)
```

the output:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 4.2 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.83 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! I got there myself eventually, but have some points anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about python/numpy internals, but here's what I assume is happening. By just looking at the code, I get the impression that `finline` is doing more work than `freturn`, since `finline` has all the statements that `freturn` does (`x + 1.0`) and more.

Maybe this explains what's going on:

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(N)
>>> y = np.zeros(N)
>>> super(np.ndarray, y).__repr__()
Out[33]: '<numpy.ndarray object at 0x24c9c80>'
>>> finline(x, y)
>>> y     # see that y was modified
Out[35]: 
array([ 1.92772158,  1.47729293,  1.96549695, ...,  1.37821499,
        1.8672971 ,  1.17013856])
>>> super(np.ndarray, y).__repr__()
Out[36]: '<numpy.ndarray object at 0x24c9c80>'  # address of y did not change
>>> y = freturn(x)
>>> super(np.ndarray, y).__repr__()
Out[38]: '<numpy.ndarray object at 0x24c9fc0>'  # address of y changed
```

So essentially, I think that `finline` is doing more work because it has to iterate over the elements of y and initialize each of them to the array returned by the `x + 1.0` operation. On the other hand, `y = freturn(x)` probably just reinitializes the value of the `y` pointer to be equal to the address of the array initialized by the `x + 1.0` operation.

Comment: Ok, I think you're saying that the inline version is doing an extra copy, i.e. the RHS of the calculation produces an intermediate that gets assigned to the memory of inline-y as a separate step?  Perhaps.  I am looking at the output of `dis.dis()` now...

Comment: @cjrh, yes, there will be an intermediate in this case. To avoid the intermediate you can do this: `y[:] = x, y += 1.0`. Is it faster?

Comment: @cjrh: That's right. I assume that this is sort of like the difference between copy and move constructors in C++.

Comment: @RomanL: I added a version for your suggestion. It appears to be slower than the others.  I also added a `np.add()` version, which is now the fastest.

Comment: @cjrh: I don't see a reason why it would be slower, and it _is_ faster on my machine. Of course, `np.add` is the way to go.

Comment: @RomanL I agree that it's odd, but I've run the timings again and again as above on my (Xeon) machine and the numbers above are very consistent.

Comment: @cjrh: Very consistent (the other way around) on my machine as well, but it is an i5m laptop. I guess the extended instruction set or something else special about your CPU might be the reason for the difference.